# Endless stream of "Suspicious packet count xxx when bytes xxx for flow xxxx" followed by "Flow details for excess packet count <private>" in Console

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina, ethernet

I have a 2018 MacBook Air Retina.
Fresh reinstall of macOS Catalina (10.15.5). Nothing installed except apple numbers, pages and google chrome.
After a few hours, after noticing that on idle the fans are spinning at maximim, I opened Console.

In "Errors" I  have an endless stream of
"error 09:41:36.901853+0300 symptomsd Suspicious packet count 121 when bytes 968 for flow 7434"

and

"error 09:45:08.399365+0300 symptomsd Flow details for excess packet count "

If I check Network Utility I see that the packages are sent via the Ethernet network interface.

And this goes on forever, and my macbook is getting really hot and slow, to the point I can't use it anymore.
This continues even after I turn off wifi.
I did SMC and NVRAM resets, nothing.

[image: screenshot from network utility]

Comment: Remove Chrome.  See if you still have the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, the `symptomsd` "Suspicious packet count" is caused by a problem with the Apple Wallet. Go to `System Preferences` -> `Wallet & Apple Pay` (on Catalina, might be different on other versions of macOS) and verify that all your cards are still good.

You might also see errors like "SEID Changed" or "Hardware has changed" or complaints from `nfcd` if you have restored a wallet backup to a different computer (or a repaired computer that had its T2 chip replaced).